# Ctrl+Arrow keys, multiword variable names and eclipse pydev

Tags: java, python, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, pydev

**Caveat**: I'm not sure if this post might be better suited for SuperUser or some other forum in the SE Family. If you know of a more appropriate place for this post, please let me know, and I will migrate it.

I know that eclipse for Java extends the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> shortcuts to move the cursor within camelCased multiword variable names. This is a feature I really like about eclipse.

However, this feature seems to be absent when I use the PyDev plugin for python programming on eclipse.

Does anyone know how I can get/enable this feature in PyDev (or does it just not exist right now)

Thank you

Comment: FYI, [this question is in the right place](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20251/where-to-ask-a-question-about-an-ide).

Comment: @F.J: Thank you! I had that /exact/ problem when I was trying to decide where to put it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open feature request for exactly this on PyDev's sourceforge page, [see here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3072381&group_id=85796&atid=577332). I guess this confirms that it "does not exist right now".

The request is originally from 2010 but apparently hasn't received much attention yet. Maybe you can add your voice to the feature request to get it done sooner though.

Comment: Even better would be a patch :)